# How to display bill in android?

Tags: android, list

I want to display bill in list like following format

```
2000
 200
  20
   2
 150
```

can any one suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Listview** and inside each listitem use a linearLayout which contain a textView with right Align. Place  your all text(i.e. amount there ) dynamically.

also use **setDivider(null)** for listView .

Answer (score 0):

Here is [tutorial for `ListView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). But you should really invest some time into learning Android basics.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [DecimalFormat class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Unfortunately it cannot handle irregularly placed grouping separators. So, best to write your own string manupulcation function that will split the string version of the number into custom groups.